# Time complexity and add() in list

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

Here's an algorithm. Since it's just a for loop I would see it as O(N), but I've been told it's O(N2). I've been told that it's because of list.add, but that doesn't change N? So why the change in time complexity?

```
public static void mystery3(List<String> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            String first = list.remove(i);
            list.add(i + 1, first);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That depends of the actual implementation of the List interface.

Comment: It's a simple loop, but what do you think list.remove(i) is doing? What is its time complexity?

Comment: It removes an index which is just O(1)? Unless of course it's an object... which String is, so that's O(N).

Comment: No, that's not what it does. set() does that. remove() removes an element and changes the size of the list. If it's backed by an array, all the elements after the index must be moved towards the beginning of the array. If it's a linked list, it has to go until the ith element, and remove the node. Read the javadoc.

Comment: add(o) is O(1), while add(x, o) is O(n) because it needs to shift all subsequent Objects down in the List. remove(o) is O(n) because it needs to shift all subsequent Objects up in the List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an array (Arraylist), `remove(i)` takes O(n) and the `add(...)` takes O(n). That's because finding element at index i takes O(1) but resizing takes O(n).

If you use an linked list, `remove(i)` takes O(n) and `add(...) takes O(n). That's because finding element at index i takes O(n) and removing takes O(1).

Since you a calling the methods n/2 times, its whole runtime is O(n^2).

Comment: when two operations are of O(N) and they are not nested , the result complexity is still O(N) not O(N^2). (or in your case O(N/2))

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi They are nested, because it's O(n) times remove and add O(n), or better O(n/2 * 1) + O(n/2 * n ), resulting in a O(n/2) + O(n^2/2). Since we consider the highest runtime, it's O(n^2/2) with ultimately, after removing constant values results in a quadratic runtime, i.e. O(n^2).

Comment: @Hannes : Thanks for your reply.I get it. It was my mistake. :)